# Is it possible to only allow scroll when the finger is in the scroll thumb?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I got the following activity:

[image]
What I want to do here is just allow the user scrolls in the view (in this case is a `webview`, but it's not important for this problem) if he touches the scroll thumb (the big grey block), because I have multiple graphics with horizontal scroll that get in conflict with the vertical. Any solution for this or there is a simple way to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I really wouldn't.  This is not a normal way that people use mobile devices.  Your users are going to feel either frustrated or confused (if they can use it at all).  Most people wouldn't think on a touch device that they have to actually use the scroll bar.

Comment: I've seen it in another app and is very intuitive. The problem here is the conflict that occurs with the horizontal scrolls of the graphics, it's almost impossible to use it, so this solution seems plausible to use. Thanks for your comment @GabeSechan